# Trying to register an URL schema (Custom protocol) in Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: internet-explorer, url, windows-mobile, schema

I have thoroughly followed the steps described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx in order to register a custom URL protocol I'll have to use in order to integrate an application I'm writing in C# with Pocket Internet Explorer. The idea is to click on a link similar to `xpto://something/?with=1&parameters=2` and open the application instantly.

This is what's been happening to me:

1. If I only register the protocol, it doesn't work at all. IE complains with a `Cannot open 'xpto://something/?with=1&parameters=2'. Either it is not signed with a trusted certificate or one of its components cannot be found.` error.
2. If I also register a `.xpto` filetype, using the method in http://www.1-script.com/forums/IE-Windows-Mobile-MIME-Handler-What-s-the-solution-article7966--15.htm, I can get the application to open only when the URL starts with `xpto://` and ends with `.xpto`, like `xpto://somehost/file?parameters=1.xpto`. This is the only time it actually works. No errors whatsoever.
3. If I register the filetype only using the method above, using an URL like `http://somehost/test.xpto` gets IE to show its download dialog without the option to directly open the file.

I could go with number 2, but, besides being nasty as hell, I'd really want to know what is going on around here. This is the second day I'm around this and I can't find any answer on the internet about this. I've reviewed my registry entries thousands of times and found no mistakes or typos.

Here is my `.inf` for the cab install, regarding the registry keys created. When exploring the mobile device with a registry editor i find that `%InstallDir%` gets set just fine, quotes as well. The first group registers the filetype and the second the URL protocol.

```
[RegKeys]
"HKCR",".xpto","","0x00000000","xptofile"
"HKCR",".xpto","Content Type","0x00000000","application/x-xpto"
"HKCR","xptofile","","0x00000000","xpto File"
"HKCR","xptofile","EditKeys","0x00010001","65536"
"HKCR","xptofile\Shell","","0x00000000",""
"HKCR","xptofile\Shell\Open","","0x00000000",""
"HKCR","xptofile\Shell\Open\Command","","0x00000000","""%InstallDir%\xpto.exe"" ""%%1"""

"HKCR","xpto","","0x00000000","XPTO Protocol"
"HKCR","xpto","URL Protocol","0x00000000",""
"HKCR","xpto\DefaultIcon","","0x00000000","xpto.exe,0"
"HKCR","xpto\Shell","","0x00000000",""
"HKCR","xpto\Shell\Open","","0x00000000",""
"HKCR","xpto\Shell\Open\Command","","0x00000000","""%InstallDir%\xpto.exe"" ""%%1"""
```

My application is on the phone's internal memory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work following the instructions on this blog:

http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2010/08/custom-url-protocol-in-windows-ce/

Apparently, MSDN documentation omits a key that should also be added under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shell\URLProtocols\xpto
```

Where `xpto` is the schema of your URL protocol, here applied to this case. Added it and it's apparently working OK now, having only registered the `xpto` protocol (no `.xpto` file type association needed).